# Combobox Converter for Enumerations

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, enums, ivalueconverter

I have an enumeration that has values like

HomeRun, StolenBase, FirstBase, etc.

I want to display these values in a combobox, with a space inserted before the capital letters, so it will display as 'Home Run', 'Stolen Base', etc.

I already have code that can do the formatting for me, and I have added that code to the 'Convert' method of an IValueConverter implementation.

My question is, where do I need to use this converter (in the xaml) such that not only the dropdown, but also the displayed value, will have this formatting? Do I need to implement ConvertBack as well?

I am well aware of setting 'descriptions' for the enumeration and using the popular EnumToDescriptionConverter, but I'd rather stay away from that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a better way, but you can achieve what you want using an ItemTemplate

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ContentPresenter
            Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource baseballEnumConverter}}"/>
     </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

This will display the converted value in your ComboBox.

The SelectedValue of the ComboBox will still be the Enum value. You won't need to implement ConvertBack.

Comment: Thanks. This does work for the dropdown, but the displayed value is still the enumeration value. Is this because I have SelectedValue bound?

Comment: I'm not sure. When I bind SelectedValue, the ViewModel is set as the enum value (which is the correct behaviour) and the displayed combo box value is the formatted value. Can you post your Combobox xaml and your ViewModel binding?

Answer (score 2):

**[updated]** The key point of my answer is that the enum values are converted totally. I think this way is eaier than the coverting each enum value.**[/updated]**

> Where do I need to use this converter (in the xaml) such that not only the dropdown, but also the displayed value, will have this
>   formatting?

**At Binding ItemsSource of ComboBox**(`ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Null}, Converter={StaticResource converter}}"`), Please check the following code.

> Do I need to implement ConvertBack as well?

**No, you don't.**, because at runtime you cannot modify the enumeration, and even though it can do, you cannot change ItemsSource of ComboBox in VIEW, which means Binding Mode is OneWay.

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MyEnumConverter x:Key="converter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Null}, Converter={StaticResource converter}, Mode=OneWay}"></ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    HomeRun, StolenBase, FirstBase
}

[ValueConversion(typeof(object), typeof(List<string>))]
public class MyEnumConverter:IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var names = Enum.GetNames(typeof (MyEnum)).ToArray();
        //Add some code to support the thing you want to do(add blank in front of Capital...)
        return names;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: How will the selected value be converted back to an enum if the `ConvertBack` is not implemented?

Comment: I thought whole values for the enum for the converting. Is there any reason that each enum value be converted?

Comment: Well, yes, the enums need to be converted and you're converting them in your code when you call `GetNames` and then 'add blank in front of Capital'. The ComboBox only knows about a `List<string>` so somehow that needs to be mapped back to an enum value.

Comment: Why is converting code, a string value to a enum value, placed in the ConvertBack method? Moreover, do you can access the ConvertBack method? (I don't want to make you unpleasant. I think this discussion is good for us. If I made a mistake or have a misunderstanding, please let me know.)

Comment: Good discussion :) ComboBox only knows about `List<string>` - but we want to bind `SelectedItem` to an enum in our ViewModel. So how do we convert the `SelectedItem` (a `string`) into an enum? I see that my solution will not work but I think we need to convert `string->enum` *somewhere*...

Comment: Yes, I think it can be coded in Property Setter of ViewModel, binding SelectedItem of ComboBox, but we do not know what questioner exactly want to do. Let's remain this to him.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the selected value of the ComboBox to be *converted back* to an enum then you will need to implement `ConvertBack`.

I'd personally go with the description attribute pattern that you mentioned, because

1. the obvious questions have already been asked, and
2. You aren't limited to simply inserting spaces at uppercase letters - you can use whatever description you want.

But assuming you want to go with this pattern, you just need to write your converter correctly.  I'd suggest something like this:

```
// Convert method
var formattedNames = new List<string>();
foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Things)))
{
    // Format is a method to convert the enum value to the display string
    var formattedName = Format(value);
    formattedNames.Add(formattedName);
}
// return a list of strings that you can bind to
return formattedNames;

// ConvertBack method
// Unformat is a method to revert the display string back to the enum value
var value = Unformat(formattedValue);
return Enum.Parse(typeof(Things), value);
```

You could also create a simple class to hold both the display value and the enum, and then set the `DisplayPath` property on the combo box appropriately

```
class DisplayEnum
{
    public string DisplayValue { get;set; }
    public MyEnum ActualValue { get;set; }
}

<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath=DisplayValue ...
```

**Edit**

I realise that this won't work because the `ConvertBack` is attempting to convert a string to an enum, but the actual binding set is a `List<string>`. I'll leave it here because it is a start in the right direction.

I believe you'd need *two* converters

1. to convert the enum *type* into a set of enum values, and
2. to convert an enum value to a string. This second converter should implement the `ConvertBack` method.

As I pointed out, if you don't implement `ConvertBack` **then you won't be able to bind the SelectedValue back to your enum Property on your ViewModel.**

Comment: You are returning List<string> type in the convert method, so then you will receive List<string> type as a parameter in the convertback method. How do you declare the `formatedValue` in the convertback?

Comment: @jwJung you are right - maybe will need two converters; one which converts the enum to a collection (for item binding) and one which formats/unformats the items into the nice string values.

Comment: I think so. I have had good discussion with you and think your answer and my answer are not so different.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make a dictionary or some other lookup structure that maps the Enum value to the string representation.

Answer (score -1):

There is an hint that you can use as a start :

http://geekswithblogs.net/jawad/archive/2005/06/24/EnumDropDown.aspx

I developped my own enum binding helpers starting with that idea.

Comment: -1 Your blog is far shorter than either jwJung's or my answer; posting links to small, simple blog entries is not good enough. Further, your answer is a code behind solution, not a XAML solution.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I had the naive idea that it would help. Won't do it anymore.